# cakePHP and utf8

Tags: cakephp, utf-8

I´m having problems with my projects. Although I have everything configured correctly it is still processing data wrong.

My config:

- CakePHP 2.4.2
- Server: xampp 1.8.2 , Mysql 5.5.32 with config Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- In layout => $this->Html->charset();
- database force to use utf8
- core.php setting:Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
- table collation: utf8_general_ci
- column collation: utf8_general_ci

The problem: I see accents correctly in the system but it is saving in bad way:
E.G. I'm saving "Savión" but the record field is "SaviÃ³n"

Shouldn´t it be recorder with the accent? I have same problem in several projects and I don´t know how to fix it.

I realized of this when trying to get a list of Organisations and pass them to javascript, it was failing in load page:

$organisations = $this->Project->Organisation->find('list'); <=  when show this list using cakephp it is working but when I debug them or pass it to javascript array is failing.

I need to fix saving accents or get one way to obtain info converted for javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Have you set `'encoding' => 'utf8'` in your database config array?

Comment: Yes I have => with "database force to use utf8" I meant 'encoding' => 'utf8'sorry

It is something weird

Comment: Are your view files saved with utf8 encoding?

Comment: yes I'm debugging last query after save and I can see it is ok but in the database is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are referring to that. Anyway, thank you for your time and help

Comment: I found the error: at first I wasn't using **'encoding' => 'utf8'**. After adding it to the config anything happened but next day it started working. I think it was something in cache. The weird thing here is I deleted cache but maybe not in the correct order or it is irrelevant for this.

Thank you @ADmad

Comment: Furthermore, also check if the individual columns are in utf8_general_ci collation